# how to convert seconds_since_the_beginning_of_this_epoch to date format in java..?

Tags: java, datetime

How to convert seconds_since_the_beginning_of_this_epoch (**ssboetod**) to date format in java..?

for example:
I will have number in **ssboetod** format:

> 987777000

And I want it to be in normal date format:

> Fri Apr 20 20:00:00 2001.

Comment: Which epoch? The term "this" epoch isn't terribly descriptive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "this epoch" you mean the normal unix epoch, you can just multiply by 1000:

```
Date dt = new Date(987777000000L);
```

Java dates are measured in *milliseconds* since the Unix epoch.

As ever though, I would strongly recommend that you look at using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) instead of the built-in Java date/time APIs... Joda Time is *much* nicer. (You'd still use the same value to construct an `Instant` though.)

Answer (score 1):

Look up the javadoc for `java.util.Date(long)`

Answer (score 0):

[java.text.DateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
    long s = 987777000L * 1000L;
    Date d = new Date(s);
    System.out.println(d);
```