# Date format in java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert seconds_since_the_beginning_of_this_epoch to date format in java..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714398/how-to-convert-seconds-since-the-beginning-of-this-epoch-to-date-format-in-java)

hi i have "1304054138" in ssboetod . I want to display it in this  "21 Apr 2011 11:46:00 AM IST" format. How i can do this in java code... ?

Comment: it's not exactly a duplicate because the DateFormat part is not covered well in the other question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy hh:mm:ss a z")
String result = sdf.format(new Date(timestamp));
```

if `timestamp` is a `String`, you can obtain the long version by calling `Long.parseLong(string)`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
// creat date format
DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
    DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG);
// set time zone
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("IST"));
// create and format date
String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(new Date(Long.valueOf("1304054138")));
// write out
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```