# Shell script (running sed in loop) not completing with large files

Tags: bash, shell

Given below is my code for getting the converted data into a new file.

```
cat Report.csv > /tmp/report.part

while read line
do
comp1=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}')
timestamp=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1}')
converted=$(ssboetod "$timestamp")
sed -i "s/$timestamp/$converted/g" Report.csv
done < /tmp/report.part
```

My input file has data as given below:

```
1424412109,ABC
1424407352,XYZ
1424424533,DEF
```

Expected output is:

```
Fri Feb 20 11:31:49 2015,ABC
Fri Feb 20 10:12:32 2015,XYZ 
Fri Feb 20 14:58:53 2015,DEF
```

Looking at the above code and the files, I think we are clear on what is required. I just want to convert the long format date into the date format. The code is working all fine. If I have small number of rows then there is no issue at all. I am currently working with a large file, which has 150,000 records. The code is stuck and doesn't exit at all. Can anyone please help me out with what I have missed here.

Comment: I guess `$comp1` is superfluous. Apart from that, the rest looks good. Could it be `ssboetod` not working?

Comment: Its all working when the data is lets say 10 rows.

Comment: If it is that long, maybe the command is taking ages to execute. Try to see if it is just slow by printing something on each iteration. This way you will be able to see if it is the speed or another thing. Also, what is `ssboetod`? If it is an external command that requires time, this can be the problem.

Comment: I tried doing echo, you are right execution is very slow. ssboetod is used to convert the long date to date format, "ssboetod" means "seconds since beginning of epoch to date".

Comment: @Programmer, maybe try using what I did, i.e. something like `$(date +'%a %m %d %H:%M:%S %Y' -d @$timestamp)` directly, instead of `ssboetod`

Comment: @NickB, even that is only necessary in older versions of bash -- current 4.x (maybe 4.2 or 4.3?) has date formatting built into printf, eliminating even the fork/exec involved in your suggestion above.

Comment: The claim that the code is "stuck", by the way, is simply false. It would exit, if you gave it enough hours/days/years to operate. If you ran your script with `bash -x yourscript`, or added echo commands to log to stderr, you'd see that it was doing things, not truly stuck.

Comment: I thought the issue is by using "/g". Even after removing latency is still same. Should I try with cut / paste, instead of sed?

Answer (score 3):

This looks suspiciously similar to [an earlier question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28011229/replacing-a-string-in-a-file-using-bash-shell-script/28011472#28011472) but if we assume that the report contains multiple time stamps and you want to convert all of them, maybe try

```
cut -d, -f1 Report.csv |
sort -u |
while read timestamp; do
    converted=$(ssboetod "$timestamp")
    echo "s/$timestamp/$converted/"
done |
sed -i -f - Report.csv
```

... assuming your `sed` can tolerate the `-f -` to read a script from standard input (not all variants can do that, but Linux should be fine).

By opening, reading, and writing back `Report.csv` from start to end only once (plus another read through to read the timestamps), this should be massively faster than your script, which rewrites the entire file once for every line in the file, sometimes needlessly.

Comment: Yes, question is similar and the way I have handled is based on your reply itself. But my problem here is not with the working of the code. With less number of records its all fine. Issue comes where there is more than 1 lakh rows.

Comment: Like @NickB is suggesting, the remaining bottleneck is probably the external utility.  Try with `date` instead.  But with a single `sed` script instead of rewriting the file 100,000 times, this should already be significantly faster.

Comment: Also, please note that [Indian numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) are not widely understood outside your region.

Comment: @Programmer, your original was something like O(n^2) with the length of the input file, since it rewrote the entire file for each line. A solution that's done right will be O(n) instead. Thus, this *does* address your performance problem.

Comment: Can you please let me know why is "sort -u" used here?

Comment: It's to prevent duplicate timestamps, in order to not try to replace something which was already replaced.  If you don't have duplicate timestamps, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could approach it a slightly simpler (and much faster) way, by only modifying the file *once*, but using multiple `sed` replacements:

```
#! /bin/bash
infile='Report.csv'

while read line
do
    timestamp=$(echo "$line" | awk -F, '{print $1}')
    converted=$(ssboetod "$timestamp")
    script="s/$timestamp/$converted/g; $script"
done < "$infile"

cp "$infile" .backup.csv
sed -i -e "$script" "$infile"
```

I had to guess what your `ssboetod` did, so for testing I used:

```
converted=$(date +'%a %m %d %H:%M:%S %Y' -d @$timestamp)
```

which works near enough (bar timezones, maybe).

Comment: in fact, to get the `timestamp` it would be even faster to just say `while IFS="," read timestamp rest`, and then `$timestamp` will contain the first column.

Comment: Yep.. though I wanted to leave it resembling the original where possible

Comment: This will only replace the timestamp from the last line of the file.

Comment: Needs more quotes to be correct. `echo "$line"`, not `echo $line`; `cp "$infile"`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help :)

I changed my while loop as suggested by tripleee. Given below is the code, which is working perfectly fine and delay also in seconds.

```
cut -d, -f1 Report.csv |
sort -u |
while read timestamp; do
    converted=$(ssboetod "$timestamp")
    echo "s/$timestamp/$converted/"
done |
sed -i -f - Report.csv
```